# How to take full page screenshot whichhas to be scrolled

Tags: protractor

[image]How to scroll a down a website and take screenshot using protractor.I have attached the code I have tried.

```html
function writeScreenShot(data: string, filename: string) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
  }
 // var foo = element(by.id('foo'));
  
  //of element
  //foo.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
    //writeScreenShot(png, 'foo.png');
  //});
  browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)');
  //of entire page in viewport
  browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
    writeScreenShot(png, 'foo.png');
  });
```

Comment: @PDHide Pls see to this question

Comment: What's the problem? Is it not scrolling to the page you want to or is it not taking the screenshot?

Comment: @RudreshuarGalangcoIts not scrolling its taking the screenshot of the page in view.There is no webelement in the page .The website contains only the image and I have to take full page screenshot.I have added the image with it. I have to take just the image not remaining right side blank portion

Comment: @RudreshuarGalangco

Comment: Of course screenshot would only take a capture of the one you're seeing in the screen. If you want to capture the whole image I suggest zooming out the browser using `browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");` (Change 50% value until your screen shows the whole image) then taking the screenshot after. You could also change the height of your browser using `browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(320, 2000);` (Change 2000 until your screen shows the whole image)

Comment: @RudreshuarGalangco Perhaps I tried this exactly But my requirement is to take scrolling screenshot .I tried  Shutterbug.shootPage(driver, Capture.FULL_SCROLL).save();
    driver.quit();  this through selenium but my requirement is through protractor.Can I do this same piece of code in protractor